# dropdown button in cocoa

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, nsbutton

I am trying to create a button showing an NSMenu like the action button of the finder (the one with teh gear icon) but do not know how to start. Do you have any idea to achieve this?

Thanks and regards,

Answer (score 7, accepted):

That's an NSPopUpButton set to pull-down behavior. You can set that in IB.